# How to load resources in an external self-made library?

Tags: java, netbeans, resources, classpath

I'm working on an Java FXML application using NetBeans. For structuring purpose I want all reusable code to be in an external selfmade library (just another NetBeans Java project).

I want the library code to load given fxml views dynamically using something like:

```
class Loader {
    public static void load(Stage stage, String view) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Loader.class.getClass().getResource(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Main class in the basic fxml application:

```
class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception, NullPointerException {
        Loader.load(stage, "FXMLDocument.fxml");
    }
}
```

But the fxml view file is located in the bacis fxml application project (not the external library project where the code is placed). I'm not very experienced with this kind of advanced Java stuff, but I guess it's a `classpath` problem.

The error triggered by the getResource() line:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3223)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add the package name to the filepath like 
`Loader.load(stage, "package/FXMLDocument.fxml");` ....